# How to do conditional types with react select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I've got a wrapper around React-select and now I want to add `isMulti` capability

I've defined my onChange prop as:

```
  onChange: (
    newValue: SingleValue<Option>,
    actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>,
  ) => void
```

but now when I pass in `isMulti` this breaks as it says `Type '(newValue: SingleValue<Option>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>) => void' is not assignable to type '(newValue: SingleValue<Option> | MultiValue<Option>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>) => void'`

which makes sense because I'm not accepting MultiValue but when I try this:

```
  onChange: (
    newValue: SingleValue<Option> | MultiValue<Option>,
    actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>,
  ) => void
```

in my implementation I get:

`Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Option | MultiValue<Option>'`

how do I fix this to make it conditional that depending whether it is multi or not the types react accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give typescript a chance to be able to determine the correct types based on the `isMulty` value.

Fully implemented and working [solution in stackblizt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kfm6wr?file=Select.tsx)

Here is what you can do:

```js
type SingleValueOnChangeInput = {
  newValue: SingleValue<Option>;
  actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>;
};

type MultyValueOnChangeInput = {
  newValue: MultyValueValue<Option>;
  actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>;
};

interface ReactSelectCommonProps {
  options: Array<Option>;
}

interface ReactSelectSingleProps extends ReactSelectCommonProps {
  isMulty: false;
  onChange: (input: SingleValueOnChangeInput) => void;
}

interface ReactSelectMultyProps extends ReactSelectCommonProps {
  isMulty: true;
  onChange: (input: MultyValueOnChangeInput) => void;
}

export const Select = (props: ReactSelectSingleProps | ReactSelectMultyProps) => { //the moment you check if (props.isMulty === true) - typescritp will determine the type }
```

sample usage:

```js
{/* since we provide isMulty equal to true, typescript determines the correct type, and thus correct handler input type  */}
      <Select
        isMulty={true}
        options={options}
        onChange={(input) => {
          console.log(
            `Multy values changed ${input.newValue.values.join(',')}`
          );
        }}
      />


      {/* since we provide isMulty equal to false, typescript determines the correct type, and thus the correct handler input type  */}
      <Select
        isMulty={false}
        options={options}
        onChange={(input) => {
          console.log(`Sinlge values changed ${input.newValue.value}`);
        }}
      />
```

Comment: so are you saying that I need to call onChange from inside the function? right now I'm calling in the arrow function prop definition so maybe that's why it's clashing?

Comment: also it keeps changing `props: A | B` to be `props: | A | B` do you know why?

Comment: Take a look at my stack blitz demo referenced in the answer. It is working. If you want more help, please provide your own stack blitz or similar demo site